# Permissions error encountered during Oracle materialized view creation

Tags: oracle, materialized-views, oracle19c

I am trying to create a materialized view in Oracle 19C.
The schema I'm creating it in (schema B) has CREATE TABLE and CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW permissions and when I run the following code

`create materialized view matview_info build immediate  refresh on demand as select * from a.info;`

it generates the view perfectly well.

However, when I drop the materialized view and then try and set it up again, but with automatic refresh through refresh fast start as follows:

`CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW matview_info BUILD IMMEDIATE  REFRESH FAST START WITH (SYSDATE) NEXT ((SYSDATE) + 3/ 24) WITH ROWID ON DEMAND DISABLE QUERY REWRITE AS SELECT * FROM a.info;`

I receive the following error message:
[Error] Execution (16: 25): ORA-12018: following error encountered during code generation for "B"."MATVIEW_INFO"
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

My TOAD client indicates the error is referencing the 'a.info' table - but this is working fine when I don't include the 'fast start' part of the code. I also have set up a materialized view log on the base table.

Execution of a simple select on a.info from schema B returns data from the table. When logged in as schema A, I have given schema B select and references on a.info.

Can anyone advise please as to the cause of this ORA-00942 error and how I can potentially solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you create a materialized view log on the source table and grant select access to that as well?

Comment: Oh, no I didn't. How do I find out the name of the view log to grant select to that please?

Comment: it would have a name like `MLOG$...`. it won't exist by default; you'll have to create it with the `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG` command, and grant select on the MLOG$... table to the schema with the materialized view. MV Logs are required for fast refresh materialized views.

Comment: Thanks - found it and SELECT granted. Unfortunately, I've now hit an Oracle internal error and am having to raise an SR through my support provider.